# How to Display The TextBox Value?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am Created the TextBox Below Of The Body. How the TextBox Display End Of the Border when The Next Page Is Continues else The TextBox Is Displays In the Body

Comment: Can you rephrase the question please.. have no idea what you are asking for!

Comment: actually Our Requriment Is Every Page We want To Display 'End Of Report '  In Each Page If Last Page Contain Middle Of the Data After We are Display 'End Of Report'and Previouse Pages We are Displaying Above The Footer.